# Android version downgrade

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Please I am trying to build a small android app with ionic but I downloaded android SDK 5.1.1 .
I wish to deploy to a device that has android version 2.3.3 but it won't even build .

It keeps telling me that the target app is android-22. I want it to build for a lower version like android-8.

Please any help will really be appreciated.
I only want it to be able to build for a lower version

**I tried to edit the version in the androidManifest.xml files on my project but still I get errors**

Answer (score 1):

->First of all, let`s make sure you have downloaded the plateform for Android 2.2 using Android SDK Manager.
->Set android:minSdkVersion to 8 in androidManifest.xml
->Verify the BuidTarget attribute, since it specifies the development tool of which api to provide you.

->Your problem seems to be the absence of API8 in your SDK.

Comment: no please i have installed  sdk 2.2 with API 8 that is not my problem .i have edited the attributes above in the android manifest but when building there are errors and it says building failed.

Comment: it build until when it reaches :processDebugResources then it shows multiple errors .an example of the errors says No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareaccelerated' in package android then it automatically modified the value for minSdkVersion to 16 don't know why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

you might need to change your minSdk in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

in the app build.gradle file set the min sdk version as 8.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.etrade.mobilepro.activity"
    minSdkVersion 8
     versionCode 87
     versionName "4.5"

}
```

Since the app is not building I guess you don't have that particular sdk.I would suggest downloading the sdk through sdk manager.

Comment: i have the sdk installed for version 2.2 API 8 but my build.gradle file in my application doesn't have that defaultConfig object above .except i am looking at a different build.gradle file

Comment: this is the defaultConfig object in my build.gradle file    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: Integer.parseInt("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode") + "0")
        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }